# API access to a manually-created Google Map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a number of public custom Google Maps created via http://maps.google.com/ - obviously associated with my google account.

Can I access these maps via the Google Maps javascript api?  The api doesn't appear to work with the manually created maps located on maps.google.com from what I can tell?

And if not, is there another way to store overlay data (markers, etc) that the javascript api can grab and load into the map on the client's browser?

Am thinking a service like dabbleDB, except that I don't think they offer write access via javascript (this would be necessary for the user adding markers to the map, for example)

Obviously I could create a db layer on my server, but am looking for a 'cloud' solution that removes the strain from my databases!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [GData Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/) is what you need.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear but I referred to that API in my question - I want to know if I can use it to manipulate manually created public maps on http://maps.google.com/

Comment: actually you are right and I am wrong :)  don't know how I overlooked the javascript api - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_javascript.html

Comment: which is no longer available. How is it now possible?

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the [no longer available Google Maps Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_javascript.html) lead me to that powerful and comprehensive Google Fusion where you can search nearest places within your own dataset such as [find features within a radius](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/circle_example?hl=fr). Enjoy !